# Посчитать количество совпадений элементов массива

Tags: scala

Надо посчитать, сколько раз каждый элемент представлен в массиве. Вот код:

```
object Try {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("hello.txt")
    val lines = try source.mkString finally source.close()

    val arr: Array[String] = lines.split(" ")
    val arr1 = ArrayBuffer[String]()
    val arr2 = ArrayBuffer[String]()

    for (element <- arr) {
      if (arr1.contains(element)) {
        arr2.append(element)
      }
      else {
        arr2.append(element)
      }
    }
    for (el <- arr2) {
      for (element <- arr) {
          var k = 0
          if (el == element) {
            k += 1
            print(el + k + " ")
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

В итоге выводит каждый элемент с k = 1, а повторяющиеся просто задваивает в списке.

Comment: `val occurrences: Map[String, Int] = arr.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)`

Comment: @extrn работает, спасибо! А можно теперь как-то вывести N самых частых?